# Magento 2.3 multisite debugging

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.3

Magento Version: 2.3

Webserver: nginx

I have a site which has multiple websites/store set up. I am not able to access the store that is not the default, and any time I go there is redirects me to the default store.
I have set the store variables within nginx as `fastcgi_params` and confirmed that it came through to Magento.

I have tried going as far as hard coding the store within the index.php file by setting the server parameters -

`$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = 'mystore' and $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = 'store'`, and it still redirected back to the primary store.

Also tried this with the full Magento Class, i.e. -

```
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'mystore';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
```

The one way that I was able to get multi-store to work was by enabling 'Add Store Code to URLs'.

Is there something that is missing?

Thank you.